# JasperFillManager.fillReport and mongo?

Tags: java, mongodb, jasper-reports, mongo-java

I'am currently following a tutorial ( http://kristantohans.wordpress.com/2010/03/01/new-to-jasperreport-build-your-first-impressive-application-part-2/ )
and he use a java db connection (conn)

```
50          try {
51       //Fill the report with parameter, connection and the stream reader    
52              JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(is, null, conn);
```

How can i do to connect to mongo here ?
Because with mongo i have :

```
Mongo m = new Mongo( "localhost" , 27017 );
DB db = m.getDB( "test" );
```

and

```
JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(is, null, m);
```

doesn't work

Thanks !

Comment: This question is better answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332373/generatepdf-with-jasperreports-library-and-mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use Jasper Reports with MongoDB as its data provider directly, because MongoDB's driver is not JDBC compatible.

You can fetch your data from MongoDB and wrap it into an JRDataSource, there are some available implementations of JRDataSourche such as JRBeanArrayDataSource and JRBeanCollectionDataSource.

For more information about JRDataSource and implementations visit http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/index.html

Comment: Thanks ! If someone has some example that would be helpful.

Comment: @LouisLonjon [This article](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/mwiki/index.php/Bigdatareportingfornosqlandhadoop/MongoDB) is about how to make MongoDB connection

Comment: To be clear for future readers: you CAN use JasperReports with MongoDB as its data provider directly. The link from @AlexK shows how to get started. (But Amir is right about the mongo-java-driver not being a JDBC driver.)

Comment: @mdahlman - How we can download the required jar file? I dont see any jar file here:: http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/index.html