# GeneratePDF with JasperReports Library and MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, jasper-reports, mongo-java

Here is my GeneratePdf.java 
    Import ...

```
  public class GeneratePdf {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            JRDataSource ds = getDatasource();
            // - Chargement et compilation du rapport
line32      JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load("/home/gocoffee.jrxml");
            JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);

            // - Paramètres à envoyer au rapport
            Map parameters = new HashMap();
            parameters.put("Titre", "Titre");

            // - Execution du rapport
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,
parameters, ds);

            // - Création du rapport au format PDF
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "home/test2.pdf");
        } catch (JRException e) {
        }
    }
```

Mongo connection and get data ():

```
private static JRDataSource getDatasource() {
        // Retrieve session
        try{
            Mongo m = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
            DB db = m.getDB("test");
            DBCollection t = db.getCollection("test");
            List<DBObject> list = t.getIndexInfo();
            JRDataSource ds = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list);
            return ds;
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.out.println("Error mongo connection");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Other Exception");
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I get this error  but I dont understand it:

```
run:
17-Feb-2012 17:07:26 org.apache.commons.digester.Digester endElement
SEVERE: End event threw exception
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
....
....
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:156)
    at GeneratePdf.main(GeneratePdf.java:32)

Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: No query executer factory registered for the 'MongoDbQuery' language.
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRQueryExecuterUtils.getQueryExecuterFactory(JRQueryExecuterUtils.java:64)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRDesignDataset.queryLanguageChanged(JRDesignDataset.java:1122)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRDesignDataset.setQuery(JRDesignDataset.java:600)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JasperDesign.setQuery(JasperDesign.java:789)
    ... 28 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the JRBeanCollectionDataSource is not the right way to go about using the MongoDB connector. Take a look at this test that comes with the Jaspersoft MongoDB Connector source:

MongoDbDatasource/src/test/java/com/jaspersoft/mongodb/ReportTest.java

Both the binary connector and the source are on the [project page](http://jasperforge.org/projects/bigdatareportingfornosqlandhadoop).

To keep this answer self-contained, here's a code snippet showing how to fill a MongoDB report. It's a modified extract from the file I mention above.

```
String mongoURI = "mongodb://bdsandbox6:27017/test";
MongoDbConnection connection = null;
Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
try {
  connection = new MongoDbConnection(mongoURI, null, null);
  parameters.put(MongoDbDataSource.CONNECTION, connection);
  File jasperFile;
  jasperFile = new File("MongoDbReport.jasper");
  JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile("MongoDbReport.jrxml", "MongoDbReport.jasper");
  JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile("MongoDbReport.jasper", parameters);
  JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile("MongoDbReport.jrprint");
}
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  if (connection != null) {
    connection.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: I read your blog and it is very interesting .I have a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340767/generatepdf-with-jasperreport-library-and-mongodb) if you could help me. Thanks

Comment: new mistake !  I added log4j.xml (log4j.properties) and i have again the same error :

    `24 Feb 2012 14:20:53 ERROR [org.apache.commons.digester.Digester] End event threw exception
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:156)
    ....
     at Generate.main(Generate.java:29)
    Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: No query executer factory registered for the 'MongoDbQuery' language.
    ...`

Comment: Hi mdahlman, It looks your above mentioned site is not working. Could you please look for this? Please try to provide sample code/Project

Comment: @mdahlman - Could you please guide on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41723713/how-to-provide-connection-object-of-mongodb-to-jasperfillmanager-fillreport ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add following line:

```
JRProperties.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.query.executer.factory.MongoDbQuery", "com.jaspersoft.mongodb.query.MongoDbQueryExecuterFactory");
```

Verify path in datasource jar file, e.g. js-mongodb-datasource-0.5.0

Answer (score 0):

It resolved by adding proper dependencies.

MongoDbQueryExecuter required for MongoDbQuery used in your jrxml. and for that use below dependencies.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jaspersoft.connectors.mongodb/js-mongodb-datasource

make sure you have proper drives installed mongodb-driver-sync, mongodb-driver-legacy and mongodb-driver-core.

below is list of dependencies with versions I used in my project, and it was working fine.

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-mongodb
implementation group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-mongodb', version: '4.1.2'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongodb-driver-sync
implementation group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'mongodb-driver-sync', version: '4.10.2'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongodb-driver-legacy
implementation group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'mongodb-driver-legacy', version: '4.10.2'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongodb-driver-core
implementation group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'mongodb-driver-core', version: '4.10.2'

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports
implementation group: 'net.sf.jasperreports', name: 'jasperreports', version: '6.20.6'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.librepdf/openpdf
implementation group: 'com.github.librepdf', name: 'openpdf', version: '1.3.30'
```

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jaspersoft.connectors.mongodb/js-mongodb-datasource
implementation group: 'com.jaspersoft.connectors.mongodb', name: 'js-mongodb-datasource', version: '3.10.2'

```
    byte[] bytes = null;
    String mongoURI = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:29002/yourdatabase";
    MongoDbConnection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = new MongoDbConnection(mongoURI, null, null);
        Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        final InputStream stream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/test.jrxml");

        final JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(stream);
        final JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parameters,connection);
        bytes = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(print);


    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```