# GeneratePDF with JasperReport Library and MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, jasper-reports

So mongoDB is running on 27017 and my collection name is test.

```
  try {
            // - Connection to base
            String mongoURI = "mongodb://localhost:27017/test";
            MongoDbConnection connection = null;

        Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        try {
line35      connection = new MongoDbConnection(mongoURI, null, null);
                parameters.put(MongoDbDataSource.CONNECTION, connection);
                JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load("/home/gocoffee.jrxml");
                JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
                File jasperFile;
                jasperFile = new File("/home/MongoDbReport.jasper");
                JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile("/home/gocoffee.jrxml", "MongoDbReport.jasper");
                JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile("/home/MongoDbReport.jasper", parameters);               
                JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile("/home/MongoDbReport.jrprint");
            }
```

And I have this error, I don't understand why :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
    at com.jaspersoft.mongodb.MongoDbConnection.<init>(MongoDbConnection.java:62)
    at Generate.main(Generate.java:35)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

The MongoURI seems fine and i think i don't have any login or password

Comment: This is not a mongo issue - the exception is in jasper and it looks like a simple class loading issue because jasper is looking for log4j - have you got log4j installed and in the system class path?

Comment: No i don't have log4j installed i dont even know what is it But i m going to install it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @AdamC: you need log4j. But I would say that it's not a matter of "installing" it; you just need to add a log4j.jar file to your project classpath. Your code looks fine.

EDIT: moving info from my comment into the answer.

In addition to adding log4j.jar to the classpath, you also need a file called log4j.properties to configure log4j. You can create your own, or you can grab the copy from the MongoDB connector source on [jasperforge](http://jasperforge.org/bigdata). Look for src/main/resources/log4j.properties.

Comment: I have this error right now :                                     `log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlDigesterFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.                                                           
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.`   I saw some answer about put in commentary JasperViewer.viewReport(print); The error is in the java code but i dont see the problem

Comment: It means that you have log4.jar now, but it's not configured. You need to add log4j.properties to your classpath. You can probably figure out how to create it now that you know you need it. Or you can grab the copy from the MongoDB connector source on http://jasperforge.org/bigdata. Look for src/main/resources/log4j.properties.

Comment: Hey @mdahlman need your help [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499579/coffeescript-nodejs-mongodb-and-jasperreports-is-it-possible) Thanks