# Spring MVC + Jasper + mongodb integration example

Tags: mongodb, jasper-reports, spring-mongo

I researched on my requirement, but it don't clear to me yet. I am looking to developed `Spring MVC+ Jasper + Mongodb` integration example.

As we know `Spring MVC and Mongo` are very standard now a days, but not sure if we can use `Jasper` to generate reports (Jasper works fine with relational databases).

Could anyone please guide me if this is possible? If yes, please provide link, source code etc.., to support your answers, so that it will always be useful to others.

I see good example on http://www.mkyong.com/java/reporting-in-java-using-dynamicreports-and-jasperreports/, but its related to relational database. Please provide me such example with mongodb?

Answer (score 0):

JasperReports (and iReport Designer) have built-in support for datasource to MongoDB so it's natural to use it without any problems. In fact you are able to generate reports using any datasource being able to produce at least filled JavaBeans.

Please see related question here and example how to fill MongoDB report: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9332780

Comment: Hi Michal - Do you've any sample project to share?

Comment: Let's take a look at https://github.com/ketonemaniac/jasper-ireport/blob/master/src/main/java/report/MongoPDF.java

Comment: Thank you michael. But I need the XML based configurations to developed the app as we're following XML based configurations.